# dns cannot resolve because dynamic dns update too frequently?

Tags: dns

I have used dns.he.net for dynamic dns update.

The computer in my lab acquires its IP by DHCP, not static, but I have set up some service on it, so I registered a domain name and set it to use dynamic DNS for visiting my computer. When my ip is changed, it will update automatically by using a http request like bellow

`curl "https://dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update" -d "hostname=dyn.example.com" -d "password=password" -d "myip=192.168.0.1"`

But at first, I used command `crontab` and let the update request execute every 10 minutes. I haven't do anything like judge whether IP is changed. The correct thing is only update when ip changes. My foolish code update every 10 minutes. After about a week, some DNS server start refusing the DNS resolve request of my domain name. When using `nslookup`, I always get `SERVFAIL` or `TIMEOUT`. But some other DNS server can still resolve like 8.8.8.8.

I wonder why? Is it because I update too frequently? Is there any possibility that my domain is on some DSN server's black list? What can I do? I just don't want to register a new domain name.

Very thanks.